# Can't import FaceTime Live Photos to Windows 10

Tags: iphone, windows, photos.app, facetime, import

I have an iPhone XS max (iOS 14.6) and I'm trying to import photos taken during a FaceTime call to my PC running windows 10.

Using the photos app on windows 10, I can import photos and videos fine, and Live Photos taken with the camera will give me a jpeg and mp4. the importing process seems to go through the selected photos fine until it reaches a FaceTime photo, where it will import the still and fail when trying to import the mp4. the import process then terminates, leaving me with whatever photos imported up until that point.

I've tried navigating the phone's storage in file explorer (This PC\Apple iPhone\Internal Storage\DCIM) and manually copying the .mp4, but the copied file ends up 0kb in size despite showing a file size on the original copy.

I don't want to use a cloud service as my upload speed is terrible and it would take much too long.

I can't find any results on Google even remotely similar to my issue, and I couldn't get much help asking on the Apple forums unfortunately.

Comment: Try the trial version of [iExplorer](https://macroplant.com/downloads) (there is a Windows version)  to access the iPhone directly to see if you can pull the video files that way.

Comment: @IconDaemon I was able to copy the photos, however they were in HEIC format which I can't open. I'd rather not pay $1 on the Microsoft Store for support for opening the format, and I was only able to convert them to JPEG using [CopyTrans](https://www.copytrans.net/copytransheic/). If this is the best that can I be done, then I'll live with it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft provides a free HEIC extension for Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/heif-image-extensions/9pmmsr1cgpwg).

Comment: Unfortunately, to open a .HEIC file you also need the HEVC extension, which is $1. There was previously a free version on the Microsoft Store which is no longer available.